# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'depcoord' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through a csv file, and am getting this error when calling the haversine function to calculate the distance between two locations. I'm confused because the variable seems to be assigned above?

```
def distance(dep, dest):
    depfound = False
    arrfound = False
    for rowm in csv_reader:
        
        for row in rowm.items():
            
            if depfound == True and arrfound == True:
                print ("BREAKING")
                break
            else:
                if row[0] == (dep):
                    print (row[0])
                    depcoord = row[11]
                    print (depcoord)
                    depfound = True
                if row[0] == (dest):
                    arrcoord = row[11]
                    print (arrcoord)
                    arrfound = True
                
    print (haversine(depcoord, arrcoord))

distance("EGKK", "LFMN")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in case your control doesnt come to "else", then the variable is undefined as the `print` will be executed in all cases.

Following should work

```
def distance(dep, dest):
    depfound = False
    arrfound = False
    depcoord = None   # or any other value as default eg - False
    arrfound = None 
    for rowm in csv_reader:
        
        for row in rowm.items():
            
            if depfound == True and arrfound == True:
                print ("BREAKING")
                break
            else:
                if row[0] == (dep):
                    print (row[0])
                    depcoord = row[11]
                    print (depcoord)
                    depfound = True
                if row[0] == (dest):
                    arrcoord = row[11]
                    print (arrcoord)
                    arrfound = True
                
    print (haversine(depcoord, arrcoord))

distance("EGKK", "LFMN")
```

Answer (score 0):

You call a print with an uninitialized variable. Initialize the variable depcoord = False.